# PHP epoch unix timestamp less than

Tags: php, unix-timestamp, epoch

I'm currently trying to display the online Administrators on my website. I would like them to be displayed as online for 15 minutes until if no activity is found within that time then they will be shown as offline.

The code which I have is below however the with the `< 60` I don't understand if that's seconds or minutes etc so therefore can't determine what 15 minutes would be. `$rowAdmins['activity']` is stored as a unix timestamp.

Code:

```
<?php               

$findAdmins = $odb->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `rank` = '1'");
$findAdmins -> execute(array($_SESSION['ID']));
while($rowAdmins = $findAdmins->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)){
    $diffOnline = time() - $rowAdmins['activity'];
    $countOnline = $odb->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = :username  AND :diffonline < 60");
    $countOnline->execute(array(':username' => $rowAdmins['username'], ':diffonline' => $diffOnline));
    $onlineCount = $countOnline->fetchColumn(0);
    if($onlineCount == "1"){  
        echo '<div>'. $rowAdmins['username'] .'  <img src="/user-online.png" alt="'. $rowAdmins['username'] .' is online" title="'. $rowAdmins['username'] .' is online"></img></div>';
    } else { 
        echo '<div>'. $rowAdmins['username'] .'  <img src="/user-offline.png" alt="'. $rowAdmins['username'] .' is offline" title="'. $rowAdmins['username'] .' is offline"></img></div>';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Unix timestamps are seconds. 15 minutes is 900 seconds.

Comment: There's no reason for the second query. Just do `if ($diffOnline < 900)`